# How to make text vertically and horizontally center in an HTML page

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have some experience with Java , C , databases , networking etc..But anything related with Html I am a begginer.The only thing that I am looking for is to center two words in the middle of the page(This page will have only those two words).

```
                                WORD1
                          WORDWORDWORDWORD2
```

I have tried some WYSIWYG software like KompoZer, but when I looked to the source code, it had generated a horrible static code with a lot of `<br>` to achieve the vertically center of the page.Anybody could help me finding a good solution to this problem

Comment: Do you also need it to be vertically centred?

Comment: define "in the middle of the page".  Centered up and down (verticle)?  Centered left and right (horizontal)?

Comment: Yes Simon, i am completely thankfull by all the quick answers but the problem is that all of them just solve the horizontal centered.What i need is both positions(horizontal and vertical).Both words must be on the center of the page

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Centering horizontally is easy - centering vertically is a bit tricky in css as it's not really supported (besides table cells `<td>`, which is bad style for layouting unless a table is really needed as - well - a table). But you can use semantically correct html tags and apply table display properties to it.

That's one possible solution - there are many approaches, [here is a good article on that](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

In your case something like that should be sufficient:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <style>

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            display: table;
        }

        .my-block {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="my-block">
       WORD1<br />
       WORDWORDWORDWORD2
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome - (html purists would directly use the `<body>` as text container instead of an additional div).

Answer (score 2):

You can put the text inside a `<div>` and align the text using CSS :

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    WORD1<br />
    WORDWORDWORDWORD2
</div>
```

the `<div>` is a block element which means it will be stretched to 100% width and the text will be in in the center of the page

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVDnV/) example

Comment: As mentioned on another answer, for a beginner this is fine, but in general HTML should be as semantic as possible, and in line style violates that principal as well as separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" way to do it would be this:

Since you say you're new, I'm showing the whole document structure for you. Style should go in the head tag so that it is loaded first, and you should [avoid inline style as much as possible](http://kb.webalive.com.au/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1867805).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .center{
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="center">
           <p>WORD1</p>
           <p>WORDWORDWORDWORD2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

These times full centering is best achieved using either flexbox or grid layout.
So if we just want to center some element within its parent we do something like this:

## HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">Some Stuff</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

/* Or this way if the page doesn't have to uncenter with changing screen size */
/* .parent {
       display: flex;
       place-items: center;
   }  */

.child {
    text-align: center;   /* If we want the child element's content horiz centered within its own container */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   WORD1<br />
   WORDWORDWORDWORD2
</div>
```

Comment: For a beginner this is fine, but in general, HTML should be as semantic as possible, and in line style violates that principal as well as separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to put it in some element like div. inside div you can easily center text with `text-align: center;` (assuming that you set some width to that div). Then you can center that div on page by adding auto margin style (`margin: 0px auto;`)

[w3 manual about centering ;-)](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center)

Answer (score -2):

To center text you could use the `<center>` HTML tag:

```
<center>Blah</center>
```

or you could use CSS:

```
<style>
  .centered_text {
    text-align:middle;
  }
</style>

<a class='centered_text'>Blah</a>
```

Comment: `<center>` is hideously deprecated and should not be used. `<a>` is, by default, `display: inline` so the `text-align` property does not apply to it.

Comment: `Center` is deprecated. HTML handles data, CSS is for display.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Quentin and @Chris Sobolewski. Had no idea you shouldn't use `<center>`. And now I think about it, you're right about using the `<a>` tag for text-align. I'll leave this answer here so others can read the comments and see where I went wrong.

Comment: Oh, and `middle` isn't a valid value for the `text-align` property either.