# Unable to place text at the center of the document in the WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms

Why does the following code works perfectly in browsers like Chrome 41, Firefox 36 and IE 10 but doesn't work as expected in the `WebBrowser` control in Windows Forms?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            display: table;
        }

        .my-block {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="my-block">Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825796/how-to-make-text-vertically-and-horizontally-center-in-an-html-page) answer ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Letky7uw/)).

```
this.webBrowser.DocumentText =
                "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" +
                "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                    "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
                        "html, body {" +
                            "height: 100%;" +
                            "margin: 0;" +
                            "padding: 0;" +
                            "width: 100%;" +
                        "}" +

                        "body {" +
                            "display: table;" +
                        "}" +

                        ".my-block {" +
                            "text-align: center;" +
                            "display: table-cell;" +
                            "vertical-align: middle;" +
                        "}" +
                    "</style>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>" +
                    "<div class=\"my-block\">Some text</div>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
```

This code gives me the following result:

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd chage `padding:0` to `padding:0px` and to be _safe_ also add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> `

Comment: @Adriano Repetti Thanks a lot, meta tag helps. But why? What it actually does?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: There is no need for a unit on a zero value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: @Guffa it's right but I have a _vague_ memory older IE had an issue with that (it's _vague_ and I'm too lazy to search which version and in which conditions).

Comment: @FrozenHeart MSish stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/1207195

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: If that was an issue then it should be quite easy to find anything about it, but I can't seem to find anything. Perhaps you rember the opposite issue; that IE allowed non-zero values without a unit, which doesn't work in other browsers?

Comment: @Guffa it may even be! I remember there was something _about_ that but honestly I don't remember exactly what. Nice spot!