# Why label control does not render DIV as HTML (AllowHtmlString=true)

Tags: c#, html, .net, devexpress

I want to center some of the strings.

I saw it.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/9536/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Examples/How-to-Format-Text-in-LabelControl-Using-HTML-Tags

So, I wrote this code.

```
        labelControl1.Text = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\">center</div><br>" +
                                    "<size=14>Size = 14<br>" +
                                    "Bold <i>Italic</i> <u>Underline</u><br>" +
                                    "<color=255, 0, 0>Sample Text</color></size>";
        labelControl1.AllowHtmlString = true;
        labelControl1.Appearance.TextOptions.WordWrap = WordWrap.Wrap;
        labelControl1.Appearance.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
        labelControl1.AutoSizeMode = LabelAutoSizeMode.Vertical;
```

But, it didn't work.

[image]

What is the problem with it?

Comment: If this a typo? "labelControl_Message" vs. "labelControl1"?

Comment: sorry, I wrote labelContol1

Comment: You can edit your question to correct it.

Comment: I edited! Thank you!

Comment: Since your question is not related to centering (which should be done via CSS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825796/how-to-make-text-vertically-and-horizontally-center-in-an-html-page and not inline styles) I've changed the title. You may want to ask separate question if you still have issues with centering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [HTML Text Formatting documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/4874/Common-Features/HTML-Text-Formatting), `LabelControl.AllowHtmlString` property support these tags and "pseudotags" (tags which not exist in current HTML standard but can be used for rendering purpose in label control):

**Normal HTML tags**

- `<b>` - bold text
- `<i>` - italic text
- `<s>` - strikethrough
- `<u>` - underline
- `<br>` (current HTML equivalent is `<br />`)

**Pseudotags**

- `<color>` (equivalent to CSS `color`)
- `<backcolor>` (equivalent to CSS `background-color`)
- `<size>` (equivalent to CSS `font-size`)
- `<image=value>` (equivalent to HTML `<img src="value">`)
- `<href=url>` (equivalent to HTML `<a href="url">`)
- `<nbsp>` (equivalent to HTML `&nbsp;`)

The HTML `<div>` tag is not included in supported tags mentioned above, hence it will rendered as standard text instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/4874/Common-Features/HTML-Text-Formatting), only specific HTML tags are supported, and div is not in the list.

Depending on your requirements, you might split the text into two labels, one centered (AutoSize=False, TextAlign=MiddleCenter) and one with HTML.

Comment: I thought of this, but I was using a common form and wanted to change the string only. Thanks for the reply.