# How to center php text onscreen?

Tags: css, centering

I'm iterating through the results of query and displaying select fields of each record.
I want the text centered on screen.
Using the CSS in the example looks OK on a regular computer screen but is too small on a Smart Phone.
Of course I've greatly simplified the example to keep it short.
The Question: How can I just get the text for each record to center... without only using 505 of the available screen width?

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
}

`enter code here`Query Results:<br>
<div class="center">
<a href="jsfiddle.net">Online Code Test</a></a><br>
``Is a site for testing some code online.<br>
But not PHP.<br>
Where can you test PHP online?<br>
</div>
<div class="center">
<a href="stackoverflow.com">Programmers Resource.</a></a><br>
The forum is very big.<br>
Members world wide.<br>
The go to place if you get stuck.<br>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align: center`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make text vertically and horizontally center in an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825796/how-to-make-text-vertically-and-horizontally-center-in-an-html-page)

Comment: Asking question differently

To display 4 strings $str1,$str2, $str3, $str4

Each on a different line, left justified but displayed in the center of a normal monitor, not jammed over to the left side

This works:

.center {  margin: auto;   width: 50%; }

BUT only uses 50% of the screen width.

Looks OK on a monitor but 50% of a smart phone screen is to small.

So how to

1)left justify lines

2)center in monitor screen

3) Use all or most of Smart Phone Screen

Goal: Write code that displays well on both a computer monitor & on small screen devices